# Android: MediaPlayer gapless or seamless Video Playing

Tags: android, video, media-player

I can play the videos fine back to back by implementing the *OnCompletionListener* to set the data source to a different file. No problems there. I call *reset()* and *prepare()* just fine.

What I haven't been able to figure out, is how to get rid of the 1-2 second gap screen flicker between the data source change and the new video starting. The gap shows a black screen, and I haven't found any way to get around it.

I've tried setting the background of the parent view to an image, but it manages to bypass that. Even if the *SurfaceView* is transparent (which it is by default.) I've also tried to have the multiple video files played at the same time, and switching mediaplayer's display when one ends and the other is supposed to start.

The last thing I tried, was to have a second view in the background that I show temporarily while the video is "preparing" and removing it when the video is ready to start. That also wasn't very seamless.

Is there any way to get rid of that gap. Running a video in a loop works wonderfully and does exactly what I want with the exception that it's looking through the same video instead of playing a different one that I pick.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </SurfaceView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Player.java**

```
public class Player extends Activity implements
        OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private MediaPlayer player;
    private SurfaceView surface;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = surface.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);    
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        File clip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"file2.mp4");
        playVideo(clip.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        holder.setFixedSize(player.getVideoWidth(), player.getVideoHeight());
        player.start();
    }

    private void playVideo(String url) {
        try {
            File clip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"file1.mp4");

            if (player == null) {
                player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
            }
            else {
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
            }
            player.setDataSource(url);
            player.setDisplay(holder);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.prepare();
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Exception Error", t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this has been posted some while back, I'm facing the same problem. Even with using videoview, I still have a gap when switching between videos. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I too have the same problem as outlined by below link

[VideoView Disappears for a second when video is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660440/videoview-disappears-for-a-second-when-video-is-changed)

But this issue wont occur if you try using Android 4.0+ (ICS). I started to port VideoView.java and MediaPlayer.java from 4.0 to my app , but thats seems complex and no luck till now. Basically it seems a bug in the native code of the older versions.

Answer (score 3):

after too much wasted time trying to figure out how to play consecutive videos without the "gap", i'm leaning towards impossible. unless of course you're able to dig down to the native level and implement your own player, Android's media player simply doesn't support seamless playback as of the moment.

Comment: I have achieved this via a hack. I toggle between 2 mediaplayer instances in a service. I have a configurable int variable such that I start to play media asset B "N" seconds before media asset A ends.

Comment: that's cool, but from experience I can tell you that testing even on the same device, the exact timing is almost impossible to set, as a device can sometimes run low on memory, making the transition inexact.

Comment: @user721448 in any case, i recommend you post your code here as an answer and have us test it out. i have moved forward with other projects without finding a working solution to this problem, but i'm still curious about the solution.

Comment: My code spans many functions and is 14,000 characters too long for a comment. I tried :)) I do not have the reputation to post answers or I gladly would.

Comment: By the way this is indeed a hack and sometimes the tracks overlap and sometimes there is a gap and sometimes it is perfect. I use the get duration which my custom player uses to populate the progress bar as a way to check when it is time to go fetch the next media asset to stream. I made this configurable and currently have it set to 7 seconds.

Comment: As a final comment I am currently looking at trying to get a copy of the C++ code that the mediaplayer is based on and override it into my own player. There is a horrible "feature" of media player that if it tries to stream an unsupported codec it throws up modals that read, "Can't play this video" and they cannot be programatically prevented or removed and it ruins the UX. I cannot alter the codecs as I stream them from 3rd parties so I give the mediaplayer a big thumbs down if only for this "feature"

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this with video playback on a MediaPlayer but I've done something similar with audio files when a stream gets interrupted because a user has switched from 3G to Wifi.

I think the delay that you're seeing is whilst the media player is buffering the input file.
So maybe you can define both players at the start? You should do define the datasource and prepare both players but only start one of them.

Then in your onCompletionListener you can flip them over instead of resetting the existing one and setting a new datasource.

```
  player.release();
  player = flipPlayer;
  flipPlayer = null;
  player.start();
```

Obviously you'd need to either use a different onPreparedListener for flipPlayer or take the player.start() out of the onPrepare. (Since you're calling it synchronously I wouldn't have thought this was an issue).

Comment: hmm. worth a shot. although wouldn't release() actually leave a blank screen right there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

Reason: Mortplayer was also available for windows mobile and one of its strengths was that it supported gapless play. However it doesn't in the android version of the app, and the developer itself writes that the SDK does not allow it on xda:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=5364530&postcount=5

HTH, Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to have ready (opened/prepared) 2 VideoView's, with one being visible, other invisible and stopped, and ass soon you get OnCompletionListener callback, make 2nd one visible, start it, and hide 1st one. 
In meantime, as 2nd one plays, you can call open/prepare on 1st VideoView to open/prepare another file.

Comment: The onCompletionListener will be called right after the first video finishes playing. Gap will start from there, and end after starting to play the second one (of course after changing visibilities). Won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@user1263019 - were you able to port Android 4.0 MediaPlayer to your app? I'm facing the same issue and I'm looking for a nice solution. My case is having an image over the SurfaceView which should be hidden in order to show the video playing, but there is a gap between calling start() and the actual start of the video. The only solution so far is to start a Thread that checks if getCurrentPosition() is > 0.

On the topic - I think it is not possible to have gapless playback, though Winamp claim to have such abilities. A dirty hack is to prepare the second player several seconds before the end of the playback of the first player and then call start() of the second player 100-200ms before end of playback.

Answer (score 0):

In your exoplayer implementation (or mediaplayer) use a handler to repeatedly post a runnable, while playing, that gets the current tracking time and passes it to a callback:

```
public interface MediaAction {
  public void onTrackingChanged(long currentPosition);
}

public class ExoPlayerImplementation implements Exoplayer {

  ..

  private MediaAction mediaActionCallback;
  public void setMediaActionCallback(MediaAction ma) {
    mediaActionCallback = ma;
  }
  public void releaseMediaAction() { mediaActionCallback = null; } 

  private Handler trackingCallback = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

  Runnable trackingTask;
  private Runnable getTrackingTask() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable {
      @Override public void run() {
         long currentPosition = getCurrentPosition();
         if (mediaActionCallback != null) {
           mediaActionCallback.onTrackingChanged(currentPosition);
         }
         // 60hz is 16 ms frame delay...
         trackingCallback.postDelayed(getTrackingTask(), 15);
       }
    };
    trackingTask = r;
    return r;
  }

  public void play() {
    // exoplayer start code
    trackingCallback.post(getTrackingTask());
  } 

  public void pause/stop() {
    trackingCallback.removeCallbacks(trackingTask);
  }

  ..

}
```

And now you can track when the current position actually has changed--if it has changed, then you can show your video output view / swap views / remove preview (ie, use MediaExtractor to grab initial frames, overlay as preview in an ImageView then hide once current position is increasing). You can make this code more complete by combining it with the state listener: then you know if you are buffering (check buffering position versus current position), actually playing, paused or stopped with proper callbacks (in MediaAction). You can apply this method to both MediaPlayer and ExoPlayer classes (since it is just an interface and handler).

Hope that helps!