# How to play gapless video segments?

Tags: android, video, segment

How to play gapless video segments such as seg1.mp4, seg2.mp4, ...? 
This can be achieved in 4.0.3 perfectly while show a short black screen under 4.0.3.
I have searched the whole internet and no one have ever gave a solution, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems to be a incurable disease?
[Android: MediaPlayer gapless or seamless Video Playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877119/android-mediaplayer-gapless-or-seamless-video-playing)