# Android MediaPlayer: Remove time between tracks

Tags: android, loops, time, media-player

In my android application I only play a looping sound with MediaPlayer. I'm trying to loop fluid, eliminating the time between the end of the track and the beginning of the next reading.
I tried with the function setLooping but there is a time between sounds.
I tried with `setOnCompletionListener` function like this:

```
MP.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        MP.start();     
    }
});
```

However, there are still a few seconds between sounds.

Answer (score 0):

*Apparently* it is not possible with `MediaPlayer`; there's [an open bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3461) asking for gapless playback that has been open since 2009.

[Android: MediaPlayer gapless or seamless Video Playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877119/android-mediaplayer-gapless-or-seamless-video-playing) also has several non-answers on the topic.

Comment: is there any solution using an another class ?

Comment: I don't have any ICS devices on hand, but *supposedly* `MediaPlayer` in ICS 4.0 works. Otherwise, you will have to find a third-party component since the base Android classes won't do it.